# GWT IE9 marking text of DialogBox freezes window

Tags: gwt, internet-explorer-9, dialog

I have following strange behavior:
If I open a DialogBox with Internet Explorer 9, mark a text and click on the appearing built-in icon the whole window is freezing. You can try this with the showcase of GWT : [DialogBox Showcase](http://gwt.googleusercontent.com/samples/Showcase/Showcase.html#!CwDialogBox) Just mark something of the line *"This is an example of a standard dialog box component."* and click on the appearing icon.

Is this a known bug? I searched for it, but I can't find anything. Do you have a workaround or solution for it?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is open issue gwt issue list. Here is the link [Issue 6882](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=6882&can=1&q=ie9&sort=-id&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars). There are no fixes planned yet for this. If I were you, I would keep an eye on this issue list for any patches

Comment: So there is nor workaround other than disable the mouse for the labels, right?